# Why is there a negative voltage?

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image]

Can anyone explain why do we have that negative voltage VEE?

I know that it's a DC voltage, from its name, but I can't find the explanation for why is it negative. Also, Vi1 and Vi2, from that symbol I know they are DC but shouldn't we have AC as well?

Comment: Think about how the transistors are biased.

Comment: You can't exactly amplify (DC) signals that go negative without a negative power supply. At least not without an offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case the "negative" voltage is just one of the supply rails.  Ground is defined as 0V by convention, but signals can go below ground and become negative.  In most circuits, they will have to be supported by voltages that are negative, meaning having a negative potential when compared to ground.

The voltage sources aren't necessarily DC, even though they have polarity markings.  The plus and minus just indicate that, if the voltage source has a negative value, the "+" side has a voltage lower than the "-" side.  There's nothing in the symbol that indicates the source doesn't vary with time.

Answer (score 2):

The negative supply rail VEE is needed in order for that circuit to accept input signals that may become negative.

Think about, for example, a sine signal that swings from -200 mV up to 200 mV.

Answer (score 2):

You know that the transistors should be biased, or else you'll get distortion. To bias an NPN transistor, as shown in the question, its base voltage should be higher than its emitter voltage.

When there's no input, the bases of the transistors will see 0VDC. So, using a negative voltage at the emitter makes the biasing easy.

Plus, if you use a negative voltage, you can make the quiescent output DC level 0V. So, there will not be any coupling capacitor to get the amplified AC signal.

Answer (score 2):

Those are NPN transistors, and the base needs to take in current for them to operate. For current to flow from base to emitter, the voltage potential of the emitter has to be *lower than* the base (current flows from high voltage to low).

If the base is tied to ground, then the emitter needs to be a lower potential.

Answer (score 0):

When we use positive and negative both , at no signal state current wastage is minimum.

[image]

Comment: Please provide a link or citation for the source of the images you copied into your answer. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing for more guidance.

Comment: Actually, now that I read more carefully this is probably your original work. But please be clear about the sources of material that is copy/pasted into questions and answers.

Comment: My answer is as same as Rohat's answer but in more discription. Should we copy from some where to give an answer for what we already know? Do you feel jealous for my elaborated answer?